# Selecting Most recent records within a month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Using the following query and results, I'm looking for the most recent entry  within a month where the EmpId is unique. The query below does not give me the desired result.

```
SELECT M.Name, M.Score, MAX(M.TestDate) FROM myTable M
GROUP BY M.Name, M.Score, M.TestDate
ORDER BY M.TestDate


               myTable

EmpId      TestId   Score        Name   TestDate
1           1       MATH         90       4/1/2008
1           1       MATH         100      4/6/2008
1           1       MATH         70       4/15/2008
2           1       MATH         70       5/1/2008
2           1       MATH         80       5/6/2008
2           1       MATH         100      5/15/2008
```

Desired:

```
EmpId      TestId   Score        Name   TestDate
1           1       MATH         70       4/15/2008
2           1       MATH         100      5/15/2008
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using ROW_NUMBER() function inside sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY TestDate DESC) RN
    FROM MyTable
) x
WHERE x.RN = 1
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3f81/1)**

or.. if for some reason, you really want to use `GROUP BY` can be done like this:

```
WITH CTE_Group AS 
(
    SELECT EmpId, MAX(TestDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY EmpId
) 
SELECT m.* 
FROM CTE_Group g
LEFT JOIN dbo.MyTable m ON g.EmpId = m.EmpId AND g.MaxDate = m.TestDate
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3f81/2)**

Difference is - if there are two rows with same date for same empID - `GROUP BY` would return them both, while `ROW_NUMBER()` would still return only one.
Replacing  `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()` function would also return both rows.

Comment: I think the CTE example is the way to go.

Comment: I typically do the `CTE` method, but I think that the `ROW_NUMBER()` version is cleaner and much more simple to write.

Comment: @MikeHenderson and @JoeFletch Both `GROUP BY` and `ROW_NUMBER()` examples can interchange with CTE or SubQuery. `ROW_NUMBER()` with CTE would be my 1st choice :)

Comment: Never choose to add a `JOIN` when you don't need to, `ROW_NUMBER()` is the way to go for sure whether subquery or cte.

Comment: @GoatCO, Point taken on the `JOIN` remark. I am so used to needing to join other tables in a min, max scenario.